# se puede relacionar una misma tabla más de una vez en otra? EF code-first

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

Estoy empezando a programar y tengo un problema en el cual no he logrado encontrar solución.
tengo una clase "student" y en ella necesito capturar el id de sus parientes (mamá,papá y acudiente), para almacenar estos tres datos tengo la clase llamada "terceros".
mi pregunta es, puedo almacenar varios "foreing key" en la tabla "student" de la clase "terceros"? si es así, cómo puedo hacerlo? tengo el siguiente modelo, donde FatherID, MotherID y StudentMangerID serían los campos relacionados con la tabla terceros

```
public class Student
    {
 otro código....

        
        [Display(Name = "Rh")]
        public int? RhID { get; set; }

        
        [Display(Name = "Padre")]
        public int? FatherID { get; set; }

        
        [Display(Name = "Madre")]
        public int? MotherID { get; set; }

        
        [Display(Name = "Acudiente")]
        public int? StudentMangerID { get; set; }
....
       

        
        public virtual ThirdParties ThirdParties{ get; set; }
       
        public virtual Rh Rh { get; set; }
 }
```

al hacer la migración me doy cuenta que en student se crea otro campo llamado ThirdParties_ThirdPartiesID, y creo que eso no debería pasar puesto que he puesto el virtual,así que siento que no lo estoy haciendo del todo bien. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. Por favor, pon solo el código necesario para que se pueda entender el problema; facilitará que tengas respuestas si el código es relevante.

Comment: Gracias, ya lo facilité un poco más.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo mejor seria tener una Colección de ThirdParties, para simular la relacion de uno a muchos que tienes.
Quedaría algo así.

```
public ICollection<ThirdParties> ThirdParties { get; set; }
```

De esta manera tienes la posibilidad de guardar varios parientes para un Student.

Comment: No es exactamente lo que me ayudó, pero si me dió una idea para corregir mi error, hasta ahora parece que funciona, no había entendido bien como se hacen los mapeos en code-First 
gracias a tu comentario y este post pude entender 
http://panicoenlaxbox.blogspot.com/2013/06/relaciones-en-code-first.html
muchas gracias amigo